# Accessing the nth element in multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

is there a simple way to access the nth element in a multidimensional array in php?

so for example

```
$arr = array( 
[0] => array(1,4,7,3,53),
[6] => array(6,3,9,12,51,7),
[2] => array(9,94,54,3,87));
```

the 12th element would be 9.

array keys are not necessarily in order, nor each array row is of the same length.

Comment: Nope. You would have to code this manually.

Comment: Well, it's not the 12th element, it's the element in index X of array in index Y. You'd have to flatten into a single array or do some logic. What have you tried so far?

Comment: flatenning is difficult in my situation

Comment: @RayS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array

Comment: Why not? `call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array)[12]`. Done.

Comment: @elclanrs: You mean `[11]` ^~^ (P.S. your syntax only works in PHP 5.4+).

Comment: @elclanrs it's `call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array)[11]`:)

Comment: Flattening is going to do a possibly large amount of work (and then throw it away) for really dubious benefit. If the aim is to have an one-liner just put the code inside a function.

Comment: @Jon, I agree, there are options that perform better, but no code, no help...

Comment: @Jon: Performance requirements aside (in this case I would argue performance concerns are premature), flattening makes the code more intuitive and easy to read. Flattening the array and grabbing the 12th element is what you are doing logically in your head.

Comment: @StevenLiao: If you believe that `call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array)` is intuitive and easy to read then we will have to disagree. If clear code is the aim, I would create a `FlattenedArrayAccess implements ArrayAccess` class and do `$f = new FlattenedArrayAccess($array); echo $f[11];`.

Comment: @StevenLiao: Also, on what exactly do you base the assertion that performance concerns are premature? When talking about a generic-use (library) function, and IMHO this case is dangerously close to one, performance is *always* a concern because you don't know who is going to use it and in what way.

Comment: @Jon: I argue that [this function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1320156/1596731) (as I linked to above) would make it clear, whether wrapped in a class or not. We can always rewrite if there is a need.

Comment: @Jon: I think that's one of the points he's making, you can always build a new implementation if performance issue arise, and it's a trivial change. It also depends on how you reason about your logic. I agree with StevenLiao, that's how I'd initially think about this particular problem.

Comment: @StevenLiao: So you agree that we would need a custom function. In which case, why should that function actually create a flattened array? We don't need one, we just want to access based on a virtual flattened index. Why do the work needlessly?

Comment: @elclanrs: You should go one level deeper when thinking about this. The aim is to index into the array *as if* it were flattened, so a hypothetical `FlattenedArrayAccess` is an abstraction that hides the implementation and allows us to swap it out for a better one later on. Flattening the array "in your face" is a concrete implementation (it returns an array!) that actually *limits* your options going forward because of BC breaks (in this case, it *kills* your options short of introducing a whole new function).

Comment: @Jon: I understand your point. How about an flatten generator? That would be IMO the compromise between readability ("flatten this then take that") and performance, given that PHP is not a lazy language but generators don't create a whole intermediate object. It's only PHP 5.5+ but that's what I would do if I were to implement this today optimized for performance.

Comment: @elclanrs: A flatten generator would be very useful in general but not the best choice here because it would likely be orders of magnitude slower; again, why pay for something you don't need? We are not interested in all those items (at least that's how I read the question).

Answer (score -1):

untested, should work...

```
$arr = array( 
0 => array(1,4,7,3,53),  // your code was wrong here
6 => array(6,3,9,12,51,7),
2 => array(9,94,54,3,87));

function getnth ($array, $offset) {
    $tmp_arr = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($value as $val) {
        $tmp_arr[] = $val;
        }
    }
    return (isset($tmp_arr[$offset -1]) ? $tmp_arr[$offset -1] : FALSE);
}

getnth($arr, 12);
```

Edit: got to admit, the array_merge version is better....

Edit2: this is probably faster, if performance is an issue....

```
function getnth($array, $offset) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($array as $key => $value){
        $size = count($value);
        $i += $size;
        if($offset <= $i) {
            $new_off = $size - ($i - $offset) -1 ;
            return $value[$new_off];
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
<?php
    $arr = array( 
     '0'=> array(1,4,7,3,53),
     '6'=>array(6,3,9,12,51,7),
     '2'=>array(9,94,54,3,87)
    );
    $newArray=array();
    foreach($arr as $array){

    $newArray=array_merge($newArray, $array);
    }
    echo $newArray[11];
?>
```

Answer (score -4):

```
function get_item($arr, $path, $delim = '.') {
    $path = explode($delim, $path);
    $result = $arr;
    foreach ($path as $item) {
        if (isset($result[$item])) {
            $result = $result[$item];
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

using:

```
echo get_item($arr, 'item.value.3.4.2.etc');
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.